# Can't parse a JSON string in Java

Tags: java, android, parsing, json

so I have a JSON string:

```
{
    "dontSend" : 0,
    "dontSendSMS" : 0,
    "dontSendPush" : 0,
    "daysAvail" : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    "allAreas" : ["Dublin 1", "Dublin 2"]
}
```

Here's my code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);  //str as above
int[] daysAvail = (int[]) obj.get(obj.get("daysAvail"));   //won't work!
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to int[]

I also tried:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);  //str as above
JSONArray daysAvail = obj.getJSONArray("daysAvail");   //won't work either!
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray

Anyone have any ideas?

The string is definitely as above. It's as if the Java parser doesn't recognise the [1,1,1,1,1,1] sequence.

Comment: Are you sure... that the `String str` is what you provided. Try printing the String before feeding to JSONObject.

Comment: Just add a `System.out.println( str );`

Comment: My bad. The [...] is in fact being quoted. I just printed out the JSONObject again... Thanks for helping me to debug...

Comment: Sorry if I wasted anyone's time... ;(

Comment: It happens with all of us... one or  more time. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] daysAvail = (int[]) obj.get(obj.get("daysAvail"));
```

you are using the returned value of   `obj.get("daysAvail")`, a `JSONArray` in your case, as key for the same `JSONObject`, and casting its return value to `int[]`. I would have expected something simpler (If I am not missing something obvious):

```
JSONArray array = obj.optJSONArray("daysAvail");
if (array != null) { 
  int[] daysAvail = new int[array.length()];
  for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
       daysAvail[i] = array.optInt(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: my bad.. the copy/paste mistake. Thanks for pointing it out @SarveshKumarSingh

Comment: I strongly believe, OP has some problem with his JSON String.

Comment: the JSON he posted is valid though

Comment: I'm doing all this on Android. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Answer (score -1):

seems daysAvail is not jsonarray but string
you can do this

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);  //str as above
 String str=obj.getString("daysAvail");
 str=str.substring(1, str.length()-1);
 String[] array=str.split(",");
```

Comment: But it's not a string. It's is definitely not quoted. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: but does it return any value when you do obj.getString("daysAvail"); ?